# CSS combined attribute selector

Tags: html, css, attributes, selector

I'm working on a class in which I need to translate a PSD to HTML/CSS, and I've been trying to select something but I'm not even sure it's possible, I want to select the links in a div with the `id="topbar"`.

Here is what I tried:

```
div[id="topbar"] p{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-color:white;
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, but is it because this is impossible or am I just missing something?

this is what the HTML part should look like:

```
    <div id="topbar">
        <p><a>Agent Login</a></p>
        <p><a>Customer Login</a></p>
        <p>Not a member ? <a class="colorlink">Register</a></p> 
        <p>Call us now: 815-123-4567</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to select the links then your selector should be

```
[id="topbar"] a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
```

(currently you're selecting all the paragraphs). Also note that:

- the property `font-color` doesn't exist: use `color` instead
- the selector doesn't need to be overly specific and the element can be omitted